# Alternative of FlingGestureHandler?

Tags: javascript, react-native, animation

Is There Any alternative available for FlingGestureHandler in React native ?

When using it on Android the swiper Detection is not working for the directions !
please Do provide a solution.

Im using a FlingGestureHandler for swiping left and Right Direction!

```
 <FlingGestureHandler
      key="left"
      direction={Directions.LEFT}
      onHandlerStateChange={({ev}) => {
        console.log('ev:', ev);
        if (ev.nativeEvent.state === State.END) {
          if (index === DATA.length - 1) {
            return;
          }
          {
            setActivityIndex(index + 1);
          }
        }
      }}>
```

Expected Result is [here](https://dribbble.com/shots/3731362-Event-cards-iOS-interaction)

Although im using Flatlist for rendering every item

Full Source Code of Better understanding

```
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  FlatList,
  Image,
  Dimensions,
  Animated,
} from 'react-native';
import React, {Children, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {STATIC_DATA} from '../constant/dummy-data/static-data';
//screensItem
import HeaderItems from '../components/header-items/hearder-items';
import {scale} from 'react-native-size-matters';
import {
  Directions,
  FlingGestureHandler,
  State,
} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

let {width} = Dimensions.get('screen');
let ITEM_WIDTH = width * 0.8;
let ITEM_HEIGHT = width * 1.1;
let VISIBLE_ITEM = 3;

const PracticeScreen = () => {
  const [DATA, SETDATA] = useState(STATIC_DATA);
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  const scrollXIndex = React.useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
  const scrollXAnimation = React.useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

  const setActivityIndex = React.useCallback(activeIndex => {
    setIndex(activeIndex);
    scrollXIndex.setValue(activeIndex);
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    Animated.spring(scrollXAnimation, {
      toValue: scrollXIndex,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
    let count = 0;
    setInterval(() => {
      console.log('count:', count);
      if (count === DATA.length - 1) {
        count = 0;
      } else {
        count = count + 1; // scrollXIndex.setValue()
      }
      scrollXIndex.setValue(count);
    }, 3000);
  });

  const renderItem = ({item, index}) => {
    const inputRange = [index - 1, index, index + 1];
    const translateX = scrollXAnimation.interpolate({
      inputRange,
      outputRange: [45, 0, -300],
    });
    const scale = scrollXAnimation.interpolate({
      inputRange,
      outputRange: [0.8, 1, 0],
    });
    const opacity = scrollXAnimation.interpolate({
      inputRange,
      outputRange: [2 - 2 / VISIBLE_ITEM, 1, 0],
    });
    return (
      <Animated.View style={styles.imageContainer(translateX, scale, opacity)}>
        <Image
          source={{uri: item.poster}}
          style={styles.imgStyle}
          resizeMode="cover"
        />
      </Animated.View>
    );
  };
  return (
    <FlingGestureHandler
      key="left"
      direction={Directions.LEFT}
      onHandlerStateChange={({ev}) => {
        console.log('ev:', ev);
        if (ev.nativeEvent.state === State.END) {
          if (index === DATA.length - 1) {
            return;
          }
          {
            setActivityIndex(index + 1);
          }
        }
      }}>
      <FlingGestureHandler
        key="right"
        direction={Directions.RIGHT}
        onHandlerStateChange={({ev}) => {
          console.log('ev:', ev);
          if (ev.nativeEvent.state === State.END) {
            if (index === 0) {
              return;
            }
            {
              setActivityIndex(index - 1);
            }
          }
        }}>
        <View style={styles.MainContainer}>
          {DATA.map((item, index) => {
            const inputRange = [-1, 0, 1];

            const translateY = scrollXIndex.interpolate({
              inputRange,
              outputRange: [scale(70), 0, scale(-70)],
            });
            <Animated.Image
              key={`image-${index}`}
              style={[
                StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
                {transform: [{translateY}]},
              ]}
              source={{
                uri: item.poster,
              }}
              blurRadius={40}
            />;
          })}
          <HeaderItems DATA={DATA} scrollXAnimation={scrollXAnimation} />
          <FlatList
            data={DATA}
            keyExtractor={(_, inx) => String(inx)}
            horizontal
            inverted={true}
            contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainerStyle}
            CellRendererComponent={({
              item,
              index,
              children,
              style,
              ...props
            }) => {
              const newStyle = [style, {zIndex: DATA.length - index}];

              return (
                <View style={newStyle} index={index} {...props}>
                  {children}
                </View>
              );
            }}
            initialNumToRender={DATA.length}
            scrollEnabled={false}
            removeClippedSubviews={false}
            renderItem={renderItem}
          />
        </View>
      </FlingGestureHandler>
    </FlingGestureHandler>
  );
};

export default PracticeScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  MainContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: scale(20),
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  imageContainer: (translateX, scale, opacity) => ({
    position: 'absolute',
    left: -ITEM_WIDTH / 2.1,
    opacity,
    transform: [{translateX}, {scale}],
  }),
  imgStyle: {
    height: ITEM_HEIGHT,
    width: ITEM_WIDTH,
    borderRadius: scale(16),
  },
  contentContainerStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',

    padding: scale(10) * 2,
  },
});
```

Comment: Hi. Did you find any solutions? I am also facing the same problem!